Optimization of videos from Flutter App Api Call
I list videos from api on my page in Flutter.I used the PreloadPageView 'preload_page_view' package to list the videos.The videos are in mp4 format. Video sizes average between 100-200 mb. I make the api request on the previous page before going to this page and the data comes immediately. But on the screen where I show the videos, the videos can take a long time to load. What method should I follow for this?
@RoutePage()

class _VideoScrollViewState extends State<VideoScrollView> {
  late final List<String> videoUrls;
  final List<VideoPlayerController> _controllers = [];
  final Map<int, ValueNotifier<DurationState>> _durationNotifiers = {};
  late final PreloadPageController _pageController;
  int _currentPage = 0;
  Timer? _overlayTimer;
  bool _isOverlayVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PreloadPageController();
    videoUrls = widget.state.episodesPageResponseModel.results
            ?.map((result) => result.videoFile ?? '')
            .where((url) => url.isNotEmpty)
            .toList() ??
        [];
    _initializeVideoControllers();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final controller in _controllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    _pageController.dispose();
    _overlayTimer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _initializeVideoControllers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < videoUrls.length; i++) {
      final controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrls[i]);

      controller.initialize().timeout(
        const Duration(seconds: 60),
        onTimeout: () {
          debugPrint("Video yükleme zaman aşımına uğradı: ${videoUrls[i]}");
          throw Exception("Video yükleme zaman aşımı.");
        },
      ).then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      }).catchError((error) {
        debugPrint("Video yükleme hatası: $error");
        _showSnackBar('Video yükleme hatası.');
      });

      _controllers.add(controller);

      _durationNotifiers[i] = ValueNotifier(
        const DurationState(
          progress: Duration.zero,
          buffered: Duration.zero,
          total: Duration.zero,
        ),
      );

      controller.addListener(() {
        if (controller.value.isInitialized) {
          _durationNotifiers[i]!.value = DurationState(
            progress: controller.value.position,
            buffered: controller.value.buffered.isNotEmpty
                ? controller.value.buffered.last.end
                : Duration.zero,
            total: controller.value.duration,
          );

          if (controller.value.position >= controller.value.duration) {
            _onVideoEnd(i);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    if (_controllers.isNotEmpty) {
      _controllers[_currentPage].play();
      _startOverlayTimer();
    }
  }

  void _startOverlayTimer() {
    _overlayTimer?.cancel();
    _overlayTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      setState(() {
        _isOverlayVisible = false;
      });
    });
  }

  void _toggleOverlayVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _isOverlayVisible = !_isOverlayVisible;
    });
    if (_isOverlayVisible && _controllers[_currentPage].value.isPlaying) {
      _startOverlayTimer();
    } else {
      _overlayTimer?.cancel();
    }
  }

  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _controllers[_currentPage].pause();
      _currentPage = index;
      _controllers[_currentPage].play();
    });
  }

  void _onVideoEnd(int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex + 1 < _controllers.length) {
      _controllers[currentIndex].pause();
      _pageController.animateToPage(
        currentIndex + 1,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
      _controllers[currentIndex + 1].play();
      setState(() {
        _currentPage = currentIndex + 1;
      });
    } else {
      debugPrint("All videos completed.");
    }
  }

  void _togglePlayPause() {
    final controller = _controllers[_currentPage];
    setState(() {
      if (controller.value.isPlaying) {
        controller.pause();
        _isOverlayVisible = true;
        _overlayTimer?.cancel();
      } else {
        controller.play();
        _isOverlayVisible = false;
        _startOverlayTimer();
      }
    });
  }

  void _showSnackBar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(message)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (videoUrls.isEmpty) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'No videos found',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: PreloadPageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        itemCount: videoUrls.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final controller = _controllers[index];
          final durationNotifier = _durationNotifiers[index];
          final videoData =
              widget.state.episodesPageResponseModel.results?[index];

          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: _toggleOverlayVisibility,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                if (controller.value.isInitialized)
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: VideoPlayer(controller),
                    ),
                  )
                else
                  const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                if (_isOverlayVisible)
                  Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: _togglePlayPause,
                      child: Icon(
                        controller.value.isPlaying
                            ? Icons.pause
                            : Icons.play_arrow,
                        size: 64,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                if (durationNotifier != null)
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    child: ValueListenableBuilder<DurationState>(
                      valueListenable: durationNotifier!,
                      builder: (context, value, child) {
                        // Eğer total süre 0 ise progress değeri 0.0 olur
                        final progressValue = value.total.inMilliseconds > 0
                            ? value.progress.inMilliseconds /
                                value.total.inMilliseconds
                            : 0.0;

                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            LinearProgressIndicator(
                              value:
                                  progressValue, // NaN veya Infinity önleniyor
                              color: Colors.red,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  _formatDuration(value.progress),
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  _formatDuration(value.total),
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    final minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60);
    final seconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60);
    return '${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
}


